# segmentiaon fault in x86 assembly implementation of collatz conjecture

Tags: recursion, assembly, collatz

I'm trying to write a subroutine that takes in a positive integer and returns the number of steps required for that integer to reach 1 by following the Collatz conjecture.  If the input is 1, the output should be zero.

My psudeocode for this is, which is implenting it recursively(we can only use recursion)

```
int threexplusone(int x){
    if(x == 1){
      return 0;
    }else{
      if(x % 2 == 0){
        return (threexplusone(x/2)+1);
      }else{
        return (threexplusone(3*x+1)+1);
      }
    }
}
```

My code is like this

```
threexplusone:
    push rbx        ;store the rbx to stack
    mov rax, 0      ;store the base case
    cmp rdi, 1      ;compare the input with 1
    je done         ;finished the loop if equal to 1
    jmp threexplusone_recursive ;jump to the recursion

threexplusone_recursive:
    mov rbx, rdi        ;move rdi's value to rbx
    sar rbx, 1      ;divide x by 2
    sub rbx, rdi        ;substitute to get the remainder
    cmp rbx, 0      ;compare to check if the remainder is 0
    je  even        ;start the even instruction
    jne odd         ;start the odd insturction

even:
    sar rdi,1       ;divided the input by 2
    xor rax,rax
    call threexplusone  ;do the recursion

    inc rax         ;add the result by one
    jmp done        ;

odd:
    imul rdi,3      ;multiply x by 3
    add rdi, 1      ;add x by 1
    xor rax, rax
    call threexplusone  ;do the recursion
        
    inc rax     ;add the result by one
    jmp done        ;

done:
    pop rbx
    ret
```

I'm testing it in a cpp file, which

1.Ask for an input value, x, which is the positive integer to pass to the subroutin,

2.Ask for an input value, n, which is the number of times to call the subroutine

3.Run the subroutine once and store the result

4.Run the subroutine n times with the parameter x as the input

5.Print out the number of iterations it took for the integer to converge to 1.

```
int main(){
    int x;
    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    int n; 
    cout << "Enter iterations of subroutine: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int result = threexplusone(x);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        result = threexplusone(x);
    }
    cout << result << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result should be

```
Enter a number: 
100
Enter iterations of subroutine: 
30
Steps take: 25
```

Insetead, I have a segmentaiotn fault

```
Enter a number: 
100
Enter iterations of subroutine: 
30
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I step through the debugger, this is what it tells me

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040133a in odd ()
```

So it seems like the problem is in the odd insturction part

```
odd:
    imul rdi,3      ;multiply x by 3
    add rdi, 1      ;add x by 1
    xor rax, rax
    call threexplusone  ;do the recursion
        
    inc rax     ;add the result by one
    jmp done
```

I'm wondering which part of my assembly could be the cause? Thanks

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? Do you know on which line it crashes and what the call stack looks like that point?

Comment: What is the point of the "iterations of subroutine"? I would imagine it is an upper limit on the number of recursive calls you allow, rather than "call the function this many times".

Comment: Finally, there is something fishy with your evenness-test in threexplusone_recursive: it looks like you're doing x - x/2 and checking if the result is 0. Why not just `test rbx, rbx` and then dispatch based on the even flag?

Comment: As Botje said the evenness test looks wrong (looks more like `x/2-x == 0`), meaning you have an unbounded recursion. You can test bit0 to check for evenness (e.g. `test rdi, 1`).

Comment: What compiler are you using? How did you prototype your `threexplusone` function in your C++ code? Depending on those things your function may be called with the argument in RCX rather than RDI.

Comment: @Botje: PF (parity flag) is set according to horizontal xor of the low 8 bits, not the low bit.   (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit in computing, not math).  If you want that, `test dil, 1` / `jnz odd`.  Or `sar rbx, 1` and branch on CF (the bit shifted out).